# How to get optional batch argument in format "-argument" "value"?

Tags: batch-file, input, command-line-arguments

Can I write a batch file with optional input argument in form of "-argument" "value" like a python command?

Something like this:

```
script.bat -argument1 value1 -argument2 value2 -argument3 value3
```

In which I can analyze and get value of each argument to pass onto another script?

Thank you.

Comment: You would have to write your own parser for that; WinBatch only supports positional parameters %1 through %9 and a SHIFT statement to access parameters beyond %9. Consider whether you might be better off switching to PowerShell, which has this capability built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite easy: get the arguments in pairs, `shift` and repeat until there are no more arguments:

```
@echo off
setlocal
:loop
if "%~1" == "" goto :noMoreParams
set "switch=%~1"
set "value=%~2"
set "%switch%=%value%"
shift & shift
goto :loop
:NoMoreParams
echo Done. Your params are:
set -
```

Optional, you can check for proper syntax, like `if not "%switch:~0,1%" == "-" goto :wrongSyntax`